# What is causing the none to appear?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In making a program to have a visual of the dice face appear, I was testing it and it seems to work except that there is a none that prints after each dice face.
The code is:

```
def visual (x):
    types= ['+-------+','|       |','|   *   |','| *   * |']
    if x == 1:
        print (types[0]) 
        print (types[1]) 
        print (types[2]) 
        print (types[1]) 
        print (types[0])
    if x == 2:
        print (types[0]) 
        print (types[2]) 
        print (types[1]) 
        print (types[2]) 
        print (types[0])        
    if x == 3:
        print (types[0]) 
        print (types[2]) 
        print (types[2]) 
        print (types[2]) 
        print (types[0])        
    if x == 4:
        print (types[0]) 
        print (types[3]) 
        print (types[1]) 
        print (types[3]) 
        print (types[0])    
    if x == 5:
        print (types[0]) 
        print (types[3]) 
        print (types[2]) 
        print (types[3]) 
        print (types[0])        
    if x == 6:
        print (types[0]) 
        print (types[3]) 
        print (types[3]) 
        print (types[3]) 
        print (types[0]) 

def main():
    x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    for a in x:
        print (a)
        print (visual(a))

main()
```

it returns:

```
1
+-------+
|       |
|   *   |
|       |
+-------+
None
2
+-------+
|   *   |
|       |
|   *   |
+-------+
None
3
+-------+
|   *   |
|   *   |
|   *   |
+-------+
None
4
+-------+
| *   * |
|       |
| *   * |
+-------+
None
5
+-------+
| *   * |
|   *   |
| *   * |
+-------+
None
6
+-------+
| *   * |
| *   * |
| *   * |
+-------+
None
```

As you can see the 'None' appears after every dice face gets printed. It obviously has to be in the for loop but I don't know what is causing it.

Answer (score 2):

You needn't to `print (visual(a))`. You just need to call `visual(a)`.

`print (visual(a))` will print `visual(a)`'s return value. As it doesn't return anything, `None` will be printed.

Comment: You beat me by 2 sec. :P

Comment: @slackmart I type faster ><!

Comment: I don't know Sraw!, let's plan for a beer to discuss that hahah, I've upvoted ;)

Comment: @slackmart Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it